# Avoiding unwanted whitespace in Eclipse code template

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, whitespace

I created the following code template to get an instance of Google's `UserService`:

```
${:import(com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService, com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory)}
UserService userSvc = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();${cursor}
```

which results in code output like this:

```
// Blank line here (had to show it somehow)
UserService userSvc = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
```

Is there a good way to avoid the blank line before code insertion?

I know that if I write the template all on one line (which makes the template very unreadable) I can avoid the undesirable blank line — is there a better/more elegant solution?